# getting one to one result from one to many relationship

Tags: sql, relation

my situation is that i have one to many relation ,like order and orderdetails ,i need to get order which has single order details.

Comment: Can you post examples of the data you have and the results you want? And table structures as well? People can't guess at what your specific situation is. It will also help if you added what database system you are using, as the syntax may be slightly different depending on which one it is.

Comment: i'm using ms sql ,my table structure is very complicated ,i found the answer of pm_2 great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
select * 
from order
where order_number in
    (select order_number
     from order_details
     group by order_number
     having count(*) = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT O1.order_number
  FROM Orders AS O1
 WHERE 1 = (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM OrderDetails AS D1
             WHERE O1.order_number = D1.order_number
           );
```